# Newly inserted element, Colorbox does not attach to the correct event

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I have a table where I want to dynamically add a row.  This part is working fine and I am using jQuery to insert the new row.  The problem is, the row includes two links for 'edit' and 'delete' which are attached to Colorbox popups.  Existing rows work fine with Colorbox, but the new rows attach both links to the 'new user' Colorbox, instead of the 'edit' or 'delete' popups as appropriate.

Another strange behavior is that the links are correctly attached once you click on any of the older links.  Steps to recreate:

1. Click on "Add New Person"
2. Click on "Add"
3. Click on "Edit" for the new row - it
   shows the Add New User colorbox
4. Click on "Edit" for one of the
   existing rows
5. Now click on "Edit" for the new row - it correctly shows the Edit colorbox

I have tried to create the simplest test case possible at http://pastebin.com/i8n3t2Yt.  If you want to run it on your local machine you'll have to download the Colorbox JS at http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was creating the new row using .clone(), it wasn't cloning attached events.  Clone has an optional parameter .clone( *[ withDataAndEvents ]* ), which was previously defaulted to true but changed in 1.6, I believe.  I thought that since Colorbox used .live() to attach events, I wouldn't need to specify true for *[ withDataAndEvents ]* but apparently I did need to.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the code that attaches events to previous rows is not being executed to newly created ones afterwards. you need to re-run the code either explicitly or attaching a callback to an event that is notified when you add new rows.

[Editor looks at code]

Ok I have just reviewed your code and it is definitely the case. you are using the 'ready' method which runs once and then that's it - It's not triggered again thereafter. SO any new nodes do not have the callback attached.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that I am using the 'ready' method.  Do you mean the (document).ready function?  Of course, that only executes once, but it is implicitly attaching the event through the $().colorbox function, which itself uses the .live() method to attach event handlers.  The .live() method should work for all newly created elements.

Comment: yes I am referrind to (document).ready. it is attaching the callback to the event handlers for those objects already present, but not provisioning for those that do not exist. If you extract the code executed by (document).ready into a method that is also callable as a callback when you add a new node the code will work. Let me know how you get on

Comment: As I mentioned, the $().colorbox function is using the .live() method to attach events, so in theory it should attach to future elements.  There is no public method in Colorbox to reattach events because use of .live() should preclude any need for that.

Also, you can clearly see that the link IS being attached to an event, it just happens to be the wrong event.

Comment: I see that you have finally solved the problem and that now the events are being copied also. Hope I helped in some way. Happy coding :-)